# Querying Xively for public feeds - are these requests throttled?

Tags: xively

I run a site that visualises radiation readings from across Japan, formerly powered by COSM and now Xively - http://japan.failedrobot.com/

I used to query the API with a request for all readings of sensor type radiation within a specific GPS region.

However this has stopped working.

I notice when I try doing the JSON query from my browser it will occasionally load the correct data (it's happened to me twice in the past 2 hours).

Is the server throttling these requests?

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my query string:

```
http://api.xively.com/v2/feeds.json?&key=___MASTER_API_KEY___&tag=sensor:type%3Dradiation&lat=37.5&lon=137.5&distance=1000&per_page=2000&order=created_at
```

`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the API [docs](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/quick_reference/search_feeds/):

> `per_page` Integer defining how many results to return per page (1 to 1000).

I just tried a few variations - small `per_page` numbers always seem to work, larger one's don't.